# emacs - swap the ctrl and alt key within emacs

Tags: emacs

i have heard a lot of excellent features of emacs and would like to use it as my regular text editor.
the only hindrance to it is the problem of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key position [link](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MovingTheCtrlKey).
all the solutions i found are the hard way ie remapping keys at os level, or making capslock as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>key

my objections to the above solutions are:
remapping keys: would make my life hard outside of emacs, say using firefox and emacs together.
capslock as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key: would always toggle the keyboard led for caps lock which is quite annoying.

so is there a way within emacs to invert the role of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> key which will have effect in emacs alone.
the only way i can think of is to tinker with the emacs code.... but that would be like going after a fly with a bazooka.

Comment: Most OS level remappings of capslock to ctrl don't make the keyboard capslock LED blink.

Comment: Remap capslock and put a sticker of the led?

Comment: ^^lol.. i think instead of this i'll prefer to try emacs the way it is.. and after some experience.. go after the fly with a tank :)

Answer (score 4):

You didn't say what your OS is. If you are on Windows then [you can have them swapped only in emacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MovingTheCtrlKey#toc16).

But I recommend checking out [sticky keys](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/StickyModifiers) instead. With this you don't need to swap caps and ctrl, and you will have the health benefits in other apps too, not just in emacs.

Comment: i want a solution that should work primarily on linux but if would be gr8 if it works on windows as well.  please note i dont want a os level modification. i would like a modification within emacs(mayb a el plugin)

Comment: I still recommend trying out sticky keys too. This way you don't have to twist your hand to press two keys simultaneously, so it doesn't matter where control is. This is beneficial for your hand in general, in every app, not just in emacs, and sticky keys is supported by every modern OS.

Comment: sticky keys is a pathetic accessibility option for those who can use keyboard normally, so it would make things hard for me outside emacs

Answer (score 2):

```
(setq x-ctrl-keysym 'meta)
(setq x-meta-keysym 'ctrl)
```

Answer (score 1):

On OS X and NextStep there variables `ns-command-modifier`, `ns-alternate-modifier`, etc. that are primarily used to swap the meanings of option and command but could be used to do what you want (inside Emacs).  I don't think there are similar things for other platforms (but I may have missed them).

Although I have never used it, [kkbswitch](http://kkbswitch.sourceforge.net/) claims to allow per application keyboard layouts.

Answer (score 0):

i think the best solution for me is to use ergoemacs keybindings
[ergoemacs keybindings](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/ergonomic_emacs_keybinding.html)