# Emacs: how to swap ctrl and alt using configure file?

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

Before posting this question, I've read this [so thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143606/emacs-swap-the-ctrl-and-alt-key-within-emacs) and have a brief view on the [emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SwapControlAltAndCapsLock).

However, all the guides above use a system-wide keymapping or some key binding software. As emacs can be configured, is there any way to swap the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd> key using the `~/.emacs` configure file?

Answer (score 2):

By default  Alt key is not mapped to a emacs modifier. Each OS does it differently. So you *will* need an OS depended solution:

- On Windows try use the [key binding functions](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32Util.html#keyboard) of [`EmacsW32`](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32.html).
- On Mac OSX use the built-in `ns-command-modifier`, `ns-control-modifier` and `ns-option-modifier`.

Answer (score 1):

In Emacs for OS X there is a settings group for this: `M-x customize-group RET ns RET`
see [link](http://emacsformacosx.com/tips)

Unfortunately I was not able to find similar settings for the other OSes. But maybe you can hack your own based on the code for `ns`.